# mongoexport data from last n minutes of document using timestamp from objectID?

Tags: mongodb

I want to export last n minutes data from MongoDB using mongoexport using timestamp value from objectID.
example document

```js
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ec428cf85aff1e13c9058a4"),
    "key": "val"
}
```

Failed attempts

```sh
mongoexport -d data -c logs -o out.json -q "{_id:{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 18)}}"

mongoexport -d data -c logs -o out.json -q "{'_id.getTimestamp()':{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 18)}}"

mongoexport -d data -c logs -o out.json -q "{'this._id.getTimestamp()':{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 18)}}"
```

Any idea of how to do this correctly

Comment: have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think when passing query as JSON you will not be able to pass the `new Date()` function to it, also the document `id` is of type `ObjectId` so you need to convert the `id` to `ISODate` before comparing.

If you already have a valid date string eg: `2020-06-03T00:00:00.000Z` then you can query like

```js
mongoexport -d data -c logs -o out.json -q '{"$expr": {"$gt":[{"$toDate":"$_id"}, {"$toDate": "2020-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"}]}}'
```